# how to count streaming events if within the same 15 second time range?

Tags: c#, grouping

I receive a sequential stream of data.

Each data arrival event fires the same method in my C# code.

Each data point contains a DateTime object.

I want to count how many data points are being received within a 15 second time range.

15 seconds might be changed in the future, so I'm trying to be flexible in my code idea.

My initial thoughts are to extract the value of the number of seconds in the DateTime object... i.e. int ***s*** = dataPoint.dtObj.second;

Then divide ***s*** by the time range (15), to determine which "Group" of 15 seconds range this datapoint should be placed in (0, 1, 2 or 3),  since the maximum number of seconds would be in the range [0 - 59].

Each group would have a counter.

When the datapoint would go into the selected group, all other counters would be reset to 0, since the datapoint did not occur in those other groups, so they should not have a count.

If the next datapoint to arrive moves into a different group than the previous group where the counter was incremented, I need to grab the value of the counters from all groups, eliminate the 0 values of the counter, and save the counter value to a variable, to be passed to another function to determine if the variable is within an acceptable limit.

---

My question, is there a name for this type of programming problem / model, so I can find it from a web search and do more reading to figure out if this is a good method of approach, or if the model suggests there is an easier way?

Comment: I believe what the term you are looking for is "binning" but I am not sure it will help you ("windowing" is also related). Are the data points received in chronological order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each data arrival event that fires, increment a counter. Set a timer to go off every 15 seconds. Record the counter value as you wish (in a list, dictionary, etc.), and reset the counter.

Comment: Aha, a very simple system, a tally counter and a timer event to grab the value of tally, thanks! I knew I was making it too complicated an that's why I wanted to learn some vocabulary so i could read more about what I was trying to do.

Comment: @SteveWasiura Depending on how much accuracy you need, be careful to access the counter value in a synchronized way. May need a mutex or lock of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashMap to have a key as [0-59] and value as list of dataPoints.

The list can also be a bit smarter with a heap so that highest or min values are at the top. If the next dataPoint is greater than the highest element, you can put it at the top of the heap.

Answer (score 0):

What if the process starts on a non-zero time frame?

I feel you're over complicating things. I'd just use an expression to filter on time frames:

An example using a generated list and Linq:

```
var start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
        List<DateTime> times = new List<DateTime>();

        int i = 1;
        var currentTime = new DateTime();
        do
        {
            currentTime = start.AddSeconds(.5 * i);
            times.Add(currentTime);
            i++;
        } while (currentTime < DateTime.Now);

        times.Where(t => t >= start.AddSeconds(15) && t <= start.AddSeconds(30))
           .ToList().ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f));
```

Comment: yes i was overcomplicating things. thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data points are received in chronological order (otherwise, you'd have to determine some arbitrary buffer limit and just process the buffer).

On your first input, set the start of your window to the `DateTime` of the first data point and initialize the group to hold the data point.

On each subsequent input,

- if the elapsed time is less than equal to the window duration (15 seconds), increase the count and add the data point to the group.
- If the elapsed time is over the window duration, store the count and group (or send them on), and reset the start of window to the `DataTime` of the current data point, and reset the group to just the current data point.